# How to get a count of the push notifications using react-native-firebase

Tags: react-native, push-notification, react-native-firebase

I want to set the count of the badge per hand in react-native with firebase.

```
firebase.notifications.setBadge(number)
```

how to get the number?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't! you should implement a mechanism for this on server-side. Or you can use some other notification service like `react-native-onesignal`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `firebase.notifications.getBadge()`, like described in the Docs: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/reference/Notifications#getBadge

But I wonder, it doesn't seem to be the total of received messages. I think the Idea behind this is, that you add (and increment for each message) an `setBadge` to your `onNotifications`.

But the question at all (I think thats also what the Thread-Opener means), how do I get the total number of received messages per app. It should be possible, because it's still used in Android: 
[image]

Comment: Hi, I am facing some different problem. I want to add notification count. Like whatsapp having notification like "You have 4 messages". I am working on a react native app having chat functionality. And I want to send notification for new chat message.

Comment: I've figured out. there is no build-in function which returns you an amount of received messages. Unfortunately You have to count it in your App, if the message receive, and decrement the msg-counter if you've opened some of them.

Comment: Hi i'm facing issue to set badge count on my react native application. I'm able to set badge count statically but unable to set count dynamically means when notification received i want to set new count. Can you guys please help me to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @suther I have a react native app, implement with firebase as backend, so I use
 Cloud function to send a notification to users and I save it in a real-time Database,

In the Home screen, I add a bell  when the user clicks it will navigate him to a specific screen contains all notifications saved to a real-time database(firebase),
So I want to add a counter if the user gets a new notification it will increase and after a click to the bell and navigate to notifications detail screen and get back to Home screen should be a 0 count or just a bell without a counter, how can I do it?

Comment: There is no `getBadge()` function

Comment: @Kasra: Yep, description was for RN-Firebase v4. It is outsourced now to https://notifee.app/. Have a look at: https://notifee.app/react-native/reference/getbadgecount

Comment: badge count related function is for ios only now
https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/ios/badges
seems android supports badge count by default

Answer (score 1):

**RN-Firebase >= v6**
The above answer was for RN-Firebase v5.x Since v6.x, some notification functionality was removed, to keep only the basic one. In the documentation they point users to a seperated Library named [Notifee](https://notifee.app/react-native/reference).

So you'll find the [getBadge-Replacement here](https://notifee.app/react-native/reference/getbadgecount)

Comment: Notifee lists some free alternatives here https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/overview#alternative-solutions. For setting badge count, I was able to use https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification which also has an API to getBadgeCount

Comment: it's all free now!
https://invertase.io/blog/open-sourcing-notifee

Comment: @Psychopomp thanks for the note, I've edit it at my comment