# How to count the notifications coming on the app in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, badge, react-native-firebase

My requirement is very simple. I have configured react-native-firebase properly. I am getting notification as required. But my requirement is, I have bell icon in my app I want to count all the notifications coming (can be in foreground, can be in background or can be when app is killed) I want to show that count on the bell icon. When user will click on icon I will then make it to null. Now I want to know how I can achieve as above. Please help me out, any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/54090386/9408181

Comment: @RahulChokshi thank you for response but the link shared didn't help me. Even there is same comment on accepted answer, which I want to implement but no solution available.